# Consuming Own API Laravel 401 Unauthorized

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-passport

I've followed all the directions from the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/passport#consuming-your-api-with-javascript) and I've also watched the [Passport video](https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5-3/episodes/13) on Laracasts.

This all seems to focus on unprotected API endpoints, ie: those outside of the `auth:api` middleware. In Taylor's video example he sets the endpoint as:

```
Route::get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
```

I'm not sure why anyone would want to leave this sensitive information unprotected, but that's beside the point. I need to have all my routes protected behind the `auth` middleware like so:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function() {
    Route::get('/user', function (Request $request) {
        return $request->user();
    });
});
```

How do I go about getting Passport to authenticate the user? The docs suggest that this should work out of the box, but clearly it doesn't.